# Which hardware device supports <p: signature/> primefaces signature component

Tags: jsf, primefaces, signature

I have used primefaces signature component which can be used readily by tablet or touch screen , but I need a device for my desktop computer which must support primefaces signature component

Comment: I don't understand it works fine on a Desktop with a mouse?

Comment: Yes it works fine with mouse , I can draw signature using mouse but I need a pen and digital pad to draw the signature and it must support primefaces signature

Comment: So you are looking for some kind of hardware recommendation to have a pen and tablet connected to your desktop?

Comment: Yes, pls suggest

Comment: How about a wacom pen tablet.  Designed exactly for this: https://www.wacom.com/en-us/products/pen-tablets